# socket.io not working in production mode for IOS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I'm currently using socket.io for real time alerts in my app. I'm developing it using React Native with Expo.

I import this instance of the socket into required components:

**socketInstance.js**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { url } from './url';

const socket = io(url, { secure: true });

export default socket;
```

And then use it to emit data to the server, for example, when the payment for an order has been completed:

**OrderPurchaseScreen.js**

```
const openPaymentSheet = async () => {

const { error } = await presentPaymentSheet();

if (error) {
  Alert.alert(`Error code: ${error.code}`, error.message, [
    {
      text: "Try Again",
      onPress: () => openPaymentSheet(),
    },
    {
      text: "Cancel Order",
      onPress: () => handleExit(),
      style: "cancel",
    },
  ]);
} else {
  Alert.alert(
    "Payment Successful",
    "Your payment has successfully been processed."
  );
  socket.emit("order-purchase-complete", Store.getState().orderReducer.orderTicket.restaurantId);
  setActive(false);
  navigation.navigate('OrderCompleteScreen');
}
```

In the node server
**server.js**

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on("logIn", (userId) => {

      console.log("new user logged in. - " + userId.toString());
    
      socket.join(userId.toString());

      socket.on("order-cancelled", (userId) => {
        console.log("order cancelled");
        io.to(userId.toString()).emit("order-cancelled", createNotificationObject("Order Cancelled", "The restaurant has cancelled your order. Your money will be refunded."));
      });

      socket.on("new-order-completed", (userId) => {
        console.log("order completed");
        io.to(userId.toString()).emit("new-order-completed", createNotificationObject("Order Completed", "Your order has been completed."));
      });

    });

socket.on("restaurantLogin", (restaurantId) => {

        console.log("new restaurant logging in...");

        socket.join(restaurantId.toString());

        socket.on("new-order-for-approval", (restaurantId) => {
            console.log("New Order For Approval!");
            io.to(restaurantId.toString()).emit("new-order-for-approval", createNotificationObject("Order Awaiting Approval", "There is a new order awaiting approval. View it in the Restaurant Manager."));
        });
  
        socket.on("order-purchase-complete", (restaurantId) => {
          console.log("new order purchase completed");
          io.to(restaurantId.toString()).emit("order-purchase-complete", createNotificationObject("Order Completed", "A new order has been placed. View it in the Restaurant Manager."));
        });

      });
}
```

I have found that in dev mode, everything works fine and as expected. However when I switch to prod mode for IOS (have not tested Android), it only seems to be able to handle the user logging in. When it comes to emitting data after the order being completed for example, nothing gets emitted. Anyone know what I can do to debug this to help me find out the problem or have a potential solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer while browsing the socket.io documentation:

https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/

"**A Note About Multitasking in iOS**

As you probably know, iOS is very picky about what you can do in the background. As such, dont expect that your socket connection will survive in the background! Youll probably stop receiving events within seconds of the app going into the background. So its better to create a task that will gracefully close the connection when it enters the background (via AppDelegate), and then reconnect the socket when the app comes back into the foreground."

So all I did was use AppState to get the state of the app, and depending on if it was in the foreground or background I would re connect to the socket or disconnect:

**App.js**

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener(
      "change",
      async (nextAppState) => {

        if (
          appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
          nextAppState === "active"
        ) {
          if (_userToken !== null && email !== null && password !== null) {
            
            socket.connect();
            socket.emit("logIn", Store.getState().userReducer._id);
          
        }

        appState.current = nextAppState;
        setAppStateVisible(appState.current);

        if (appState.current === "background") {

            socket.disconnect();
          
        }

        //console.log("AppState", appState.current);
      }
    );
```